# How to remove the root element from QTreeView?

Tags: qt, qt4, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I process the removal of tree elements in the slot. All elements are deleted, except the last (root).

```
void TreeModel::slotDelete()
{
 QStandardItem *curItem = itemFromIndex(_tvMainTree->currentIndex());
 QStandardItem *curParent = itemFromIndex(_tvMainTree->currentIndex())->parent();

 if(!curItem || !curParent) return;

 curParent->removeRow(curItem->row());
}
```

Why is it that when I try to delete the last element, `curParent` is `0x0`?

**Specification:** I build the tree using the root element of invisibleRootItem ().

Tell me how to delete the last (root) element?

Comment: Show your complete code

Comment: Better yet, show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all. Here is the solution.

```
void TreeModel::slotDelete()
{
 QStandardItem *curItem = itemFromIndex(_tvMainTree->currentIndex());
 if(!curItem) return;

 QStandardItem *curParent = curItem->parent();
 if(!curParent)
 {
  invisibleRootItem()->removeRow(curItem->row());
  return;
 }

 curParent->removeRow(curItem->row());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition the root item is the top of a hierarchy; it can't have a parent. So what you're trying is invalid.

Seems like you're using `QStandardItemModel`. Compare the documentation of [`QStandardItemModel::invisibleRootItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemFromIndex):

> The invisible root item provides access to the model's top-level items [...] Calling index() on the QStandardItem object retrieved from this function is not valid.

In other words: The root item/index is created implicitly; you can't delete it and have to stop recursion at this point. This is BTW a common pattern when using Qt models: If `parent()` returns `nullptr` you've reached the root index.

Comment: Yes, I'm using QStandardItemModel. I don't want to remove the root invisible element. I want to delete the visible items.

Comment: @Compozitor I've updated my answer and hope this makes things more clear to you. If not then I would advise to clarify your question, indicating what your *real* problem is.

Comment: Thank you so much!